# JMeter: How to capture overall response data using Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: tcp, upload, jmeter

I want to re-use the Response Data received in Listener as show in Image below.

I would like to know, how can I capture overall response so that I can re-use the same for uploading.

Scenario is:

1. Download 1KB of string data using TCP Sampler (Port: XYZW)
2. Upload the text response received  (Port: ASDF)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) the relevant Regular Expression should be:

```
(?s)(^.*)
```

Entire configuration:

[image: Regex for full response]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, that was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

With Http sampler, I add a `BeanShell PostProcessor` as a child of Http sampler and use below script to retrieve all response data, I think it's the same with TCP sampler, let's try:

```
// get all response data
String dashboardData = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
// do something with the data
// and then put the retrieved data into parameter to use later
vars.put("dataTobeUsed", dashboardData);
```

and we can use `${dataTobeUsed}` for other samplers

If you want to get the response data via regular expression extractor, you can use the pattern `([^"]+)`

Hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood your question right,

You can use regular exp **[a-z0-9]*** with any reference name lets say "TCP_Data" in your first TCP request.
Now you can use the same reference name in TCP request 2, by **${TCP_Data}**.

Comment: Even I tried the same but execution stops and I have to stop the test which shows error as                                "Response code: 500
Response message: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.ReadException: Error reading from server, bytes read: 0
"

Comment: Plz share entire crash log and steps you did.